# AZ synapse linked Dataverse tables disappearing in AZ data lake Gen2

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse, dataverse

I have synced my dataverse tables to az Data lake using azure synapse link. I verified that tables did appear. some time later when I checked, no tables were there. Not sure why. Need help.
[Tables in Dataverse synapse link store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OElZ7.png)

[Az Data lake showing no tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iFUb.png)

Comment: Make sure you have the System Administrator or System Customizer security role or equivalent permissions to update the setting.

Can you elaborate more on the actions performed after adding new tables ? Are they visible now? 

I am not able to see any such issue during repro.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, a newly linked won't be immediately available. Wait a few moments, and it should become available.

Ensure that you followed the [prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/data-platform/azure-synapse-link-data-lake#prerequisites) of creating and configuring the Azure data lake storage account, and granting yourself an owner role on the storage account. Additionally, you grant the Power Platform Dataflows service access to your storage account. More information: [Self-service data prep with dataflows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/data-platform/self-service-data-prep-with-dataflows).

Your Dataverse environment is linked to the Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 account. The file system in the Azure storage account is created with a folder for each table selected to be replicated to the data lake.

While viewing your data in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2, ensure to select the below  from file systems correctly as per your setup.

`dataverse-environmentName-organizationUniqueName`

Additionally you can validate using the `model.json` file, along with its name and version, provides a list of tables that have been exported to the data lake. The model.json file also includes the initial sync status and sync completion time.  A folder that includes snapshot comma-delimited (CSV format) files is displayed for each table exported to the data lake.

[image]

Microsoft Dataverse data can continuously change through create, update, and delete transactions. Snapshots provide a read-only copy of data that's updated at regular intervals, in this case **every hour** to ensures that at any given point, a data analytics consumer can reliably consume data in the lake.

Opening model.json, you can view the snapshot details. Changes in Dataverse are continuously pushed to the corresponding CSV files by using the trickle feed engine.

Comment: hi, i am also using same tech, i want to know, if i export data from CRM 365, it is showing all the data but if i going check in storage is different. please advise, where exactly data will be loaded from synapse link to storage

Comment: Hi, how to add or export table column as well in that CSV file and i need to change partition as well. where should we change those settings in azure synapse or dataverse. please let me know.